# Ionic Creator: $scope is not defined, neither is app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
$scope.$scope = function($scope = $scope.$scope){
};

$scope.mainCtrl = function(controller, mainCtrl){
return + (saveData)};

controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('path/to/json').then(function(data) {
    $scope.saveData = data;
  });
```

My initial issue was that "app" was not being defined, so I removed "app." from "app.controller" and ended up with "controller is not defined". So I created a $scope to try to define controller and now the program asks me to define "$scope".

How do I define "$scope", or at least, how do I define "controller" properly? I'm using Ionic Creator with Ionic 1.

Comment: if you are just getting started I might just export the project from Ionic creator again. I've done it several times and it will work out of the box. (at least what you made in the creator) You should not have been deleting app and $scope it's clear some very wrong happened here.

Comment: Interesting theory, I thought something was up. I just checked the code in Google Developer Tools on Chrome and it claimed that stuff wasn't being defined. I might have to export it and continue from there.